# Pandas DataFrame: create a matrix-like with 0 and 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

i have to create a matrix-like with 0 and 1. How can i create something like that?[image]

This is my DataFrame:
[image]

I want to check the intersection where df['luogo'] is 'sala' and df['sala'] and replace it with 1.

This is my try:

```
for head in dataframe.columns:
    for i in dataframe['luogo']:
        if i == head:
            dataframe[head] = 1
        else:
            dataframe[head] = 0
```

Sorry for the italian dataframe.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `get_dummies`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve].  That means ***no images of code***

Comment: Always nice to see some italian dataframes! What is the problem with your current implementation? Do you get an error with this? The easiest way to do it is probably by creating boolean values using built in pandas filters. For instance take a look at the `isin` filter [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [**`pandas.get_dummies(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html). For a given dataframe `df`:

```
>>> df
    luogo
0    sala
1  scuola
2  teatro
3    sala
```

We get:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df['luogo'])
   sala  scuola  teatro
0     1       0       0
1     0       1       0
2     0       0       1
3     1       0       0
```

You thus can join this with your original dataframe with:

```
>>> df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['luogo']))
    luogo  sala  scuola  teatro
0    sala     1       0       0
1  scuola     0       1       0
2  teatro     0       0       1
3    sala     1       0       0
```

This thus constructs a ["*one hot encoding*" [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) of the values in your original dataframe.

Comment: God bless you! Thanks!